# difference between MLA's USB CDC basic demo and CDC Device serial Emulator

Tags: usb, pic, microchip, cdc

Microchip Library for applications provides demo code for USB - "CDC basic demo" & "CDC device serial emulator". I found all of them are related to microchip - USB communication, but what are the main difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally both implement the USB communications device class with various Microchip devices. A diff of the two projects reveals the makefiles and most source files are identical. The cdc_basic project appears to add build support for more devices.